# Spring security, role-based access

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, security-roles, jwt

This is spring boot security project. my entire project works completely fine however i am not able to access routes based on roles. When i try to i get a 403 forbidden error. Please help me solve this.

```
package csse.users;

 import java.text.DateFormat;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
 import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

 @Service
 public class UserService {

private UserDAO repo;
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
public UserService(UserDAO repo, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.repo = repo;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}   

private List<ApplicationUser> users;

//register
String register(ApplicationUser user) {

    users=repo.findAll();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String d=dateFormat.format(date);
    //System.out.println(d); //2016/11/16 12:08:43

    if((!user.getAddress().isEmpty()) && (!user.getEmail().isEmpty()) && (!user.getEmp_ID().isEmpty()) && (!user.getEmp_type().isEmpty()) 
            && (!user.getEmp_type().isEmpty()) && (!user.getFirstname().isEmpty()) && (!user.getLastname().isEmpty()) && (!user.getPassword().isEmpty()) 
            && (!user.getPhone().isEmpty()) && (!user.getUsername().isEmpty()) && (user.getRoles()!=null) && (!user.getRoles().isEmpty())) {

        String usid=user.getEmp_ID();
        String usemail=user.getEmail();
        String ususn=user.getUsername();        

        if(!(users.toString().matches("\\[.*\\b" + usid + "\\b.*]"))) {

            if(!(users.toString().matches("\\[.*\\b" + usemail + "\\b.*]"))) {

                if(!(users.toString().matches("\\[.*\\b" + ususn + "\\b.*]"))) {

                    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
                    user.setCreatedDate(d);
                    user.setlastLogin("00/00/0000 00:00:00");
                    user.setModifiedDate(d);
                    repo.save(user);

                    return user.toString();

                } else{ return "Username exists";}

            } else{ return "Email exists";}         

        } else{ return "EmployeeID exists";}

    } else{ return "fill all fields";}
}

//get all users 
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
List<ApplicationUser> all(){
    return repo.findAll();
}
}
```

//Contoller class which extends the service
    package users;

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
 import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserHttpController {

private UserService service;

@Autowired
public UserHttpController(UserService service, UserDAO repo) {
    this.service = service;     
}

@PostMapping("/signup")
public String signUp(@RequestBody ApplicationUser user) {
    return service.register(user);
}

@GetMapping("/list")
public List<ApplicationUser> list() {
   return service.all();
}

@GetMapping("/{username}")
ApplicationUser details(@PathVariable(value="username")String username) {
    return service.findByUsername(username);
}

}
```

// websecurity class

```
package csse.auth;

import static csse.auth.SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity  // Enable security config. This annotation denotes config for spring security.
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


private UserDetailsServiceImpl UsersService;
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;



@Autowired
public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl UsersService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.UsersService = UsersService;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http
    .cors()
    .and()
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests() // authorization requests config
            .antMatchers("/users/list").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()

            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                    "/configuration/ui",
                    "/swagger-resources",
                    "/swagger-resources/configuration/security",
                    "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
                    "/configuration/security",
                    "/swagger-ui.html",
                    "/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()   // Any other request must be authenticated
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

// Spring has UserDetailsService interface, which can be overriden to provide our implementation for fetching user from database (or any other source).
// The UserDetailsService object is used by the auth manager to load the user from database.
// In addition, we need to define the password encoder also. So, auth manager can compare and verify passwords.
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(UsersService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}
```

}

//Application class

```
package csse;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("csse")
public class Application {

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

//two user records in my database

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bab65cbf835f23eb06b0eab"
},
"emp_ID": "A5010",
"emp_type": "Site Manager",
"firstname": "Markian",
"lastname": "Bule",
"address": "Negombo",
"email": "mark.b@gmail.com",
"phone": "0777797531",
"username": "MarkB",
"password": "$2a$10$ODxFJvz6ZsfgRWELGgXmdeC0I9kZXHHIf9PHwpQZx2zENCn4lwlLO",
"roles": "ADMIN",
"createdDate": "26/09/2018 16:26:11",
"lastLogin": "00/00/0000 00:00:00",
"modifiedDate": "26/09/2018 16:26:11",
"_class": "csse.users.ApplicationUser"
}

 {
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bac4e73f835f23674fe25e7"
},
"emp_ID": "A4000",
"emp_type": "Site Manager",
"firstname": "Shan",
"lastname": "Perera",
"address": "Chilaw",
"email": "shan.p@gmail.com",
"phone": "0995534287",
"username": "shan.p",
"password": "$2a$10$R48p6mozw8BemH1emt9h3.9hOSCKb9pqwRNp2NDxk3hAQsGjp1hIO",
"roles": "USER",
"createdDate": "27/09/2018 08:58:51",
"lastLogin": "00/00/0000 00:00:00",
"modifiedDate": "27/09/2018 08:58:51",
"_class": "csse.users.ApplicationUser"
 }
```

Comment: Fist things first - your logic is 1) unscalable 2) not threadsafe 3) slow. Do you really think that pulling all users from the database and then using regex to search in the `toString` of a `List` containing them all is a good idea? Do you really think that calling `toString` once for each comparison is going to work as you expect? I read that far then gave up - this code is fundamentally flawed; ill thought through and just plain wrong. I'm surprised it does anything other than produce heat, and if it does then that is by coincidence not design. Throw it all away, then read a basic tutorial.

Comment: hi! I am sure you are an expert in this field although i am still a beginner. If its possible you could help me to solve this issue or you could just not be very aggressive with your comments.

Comment: Apologies if my comment comes across that way - I am trying to be honest. I don't think the code you have shown is fixable - any issue you might be seeing during manual testing is dwarfed by the logic issues I can see. As I said above, I realise you are beginner; and you are running before you can walk. Take several steps back and read some tutorials, do some simple exercies. A framework like Spring is not designed for beginners, Spring Security even less so.